# "Call to a possibly undefined method" error when the function is in the same class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a class with function a() and b().
At the point where b() calls a(). I get said error.
Whats wrong here?

Here's my code
http://pastebin.com/XHmyRk2z

Answer (score 2):

LetterToNumber isn't static, all the others are.

Comment: When I make it static I get the following error:  
  
`1061: Call to a possibly undefined method romanNumber through a reference with static type Class.`  
  
when calling `RomanNumbersGame.romanNumber(x);` somewhere else.